# How to refer to parent instance within a xf:repeat element?

Tags: xpath, xforms, xpath-2.0, xsltforms

I have an instance 'names' which contains names and another which contains names and phone numbers.

```
<xf:repeat nodeset="instance('names')/name">
    <xf:output ref="instance('address-book')[name='????']/phone_no"/>
</xf:repeat>
```

What should I put in place of the question marks (????) so that I can refer to the `instance('names')/name` ! Getting confused in the context.

I tried the following which didn't work and also seemed wrong just by looking at it.

```
<xf:repeat nodeset="instance('names')/name">
    <xf:output ref="instance('address-book')[name= name]/phone_no"/>
</xf:repeat>
```

Need to mention that the xforms engine is XSLTForms.

Comment: Try using `current()` (like: `<xf:output ref="instance('address-book')[name=current()]/phone_no"/>`). I don't remember if that works in xforms or not and I can't test at the moment.

Comment: Oh yeah ! right. That works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from Daniel Haley above. Using current() solves the problem.

```
<xf:repeat nodeset="instance('names')/name">
    <xf:output ref="instance('address-book')[name= current()]/phone_no"/>
</xf:repeat>
```